# New template, where to place CSS?

Tags: theme-development, templates

Till today I never used `header.php` and `footer.php` because my theme has multiple templates and I do not know how or where to place the CSS and JS files. Could someone please explain how to have a `header.php` and use `get_header();` but also include new CSS files depending on the template?

**Normal Code** *And how I see it*

```
<?php /* Template Name: Contact Template */ ?>
<!-- HERE STARTS HEADER PHP? -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Website</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <!-- MENU AND STUFF -->
   </header>
   <main>
   <!-- HERE STOPS HEADER PHP ? -->

      <!-- SOME CONTENT -->

   <!-- HERE STARTS FOOTER PHP? -->
   </main>
   <footer>
     <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
   </footer>
<!-- HERE I PLACE MY JS FILES -->
</body>
</html>
<!-- HERE STOPS FOOTER PHP? -->
```

As you can see, where I place my CSS and JS files are in the `header.php` or `footer.php` so I can not add more depending on the template. How do you add CSS files if you use multiple templates?

===================================================

**Problem is almost solved. Just need to create an if/else statement to check the `Template Name:`.**

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook with the `is_*` conditional tags in `functions.php`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Well this is what I am looking for! Only need to find out how I can add CSS/JS files depending on the `Template Name: ` (Can't use page name or id because the theme will be in multiple languages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include CSS and JavaScipt in the `functions.php`.

Create an empty PHP file, call it `header.php`, and yes `wp_head()` goes just before `</head>` not before `<body>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Website</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Create an empty PHP file, call it `footer.php` and place your footer there:

```
   <footer>
     <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
   </footer>
<!-- HERE I PLACE MY JS FILES -->
</body>
</html>
```

In `functions.php`:

```
function my_scripts_styles() {

  wp_enqueue_script('jquery_flexslider_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider.min.js', array('jquery'),'3.0.0', true );

  wp_enqueue_style('flexslider_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css', false ,'3.0.0'); 

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_styles');
```

With [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) add JavaScript, the last argument `true` means it will be placed at the bottom. You need to give it a unique name e.g. `flexslider_js_my`. Include as many js files as you need.

With [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) you add CSS files. The last argument `false` means it will be placed in the header. Give it a unique name, include as many as you need.

The rest of your code stays in `index.php`. `header.php`, `footer.php`, `functions.php` they are all in the home directory where your `index.php` is.

`index.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<body>
   <header>
       <!-- MENU AND STUFF -->
   </header>
   <main>
   <!-- HERE STOPS HEADER PHP ? -->

      <!-- SOME CONTENT -->

   <!-- HERE STARTS FOOTER PHP? -->
   </main>
   <footer>
     <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
   </footer>
<!-- HERE I PLACE MY JS FILES -->
</body>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Btw, in your case you don't need to include `<?php /* Template Name: Contact Template */ ?>` at the top. You can do just like in my example.

Update, the template name:

In my case [`get_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template/) will output the whole template path for example:

> /homepages/133/htdocs/dd/myheme/wp-content/themes/authentic/page.php

where 'authentic' is my template name. So the *if* construct to include in `functions.php`:

```
$url = get_page_template();
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$name = $parts[count($parts) - 2];

if('authentic' == $name) { 

  wp_enqueue_style('homeCSS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/home.css', false ,'3.0.0'); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man, really appreciate it! Could you please help out a bit more? I got the default CSS and JS working, for some reason I can not get the custom CSS and JS depending on the `Template Name:`. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwbuyhp1/1/ . I need to have an if/else statement to check the Template Name and then `wp_enqueue_style('homeCSS');` and stuff.

Comment: Yes, I tried it a few times and nothing changes. My style.css en default.js will be added, but not contact.css or anything.

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 2):

Don't include CSS and JavaScript manually, there are special functions for this purpose. Modify this code to meet your requirements and put it to the `functions.php` of your theme.

```
<?php
$template_file_name = basename( get_page_template() ); // get template file name

if('my_template.php' == $template_file_name) { // check  file name
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'my_style_name',
        '/path/to/style.css',
        array(), // dependencies
        NULL, // version
        all // media
    );
    enqueue_script(
        'my_script_name',
        '/path/to/script.js',
        array(), // dependencies
        NULL, // version
        true // in footer
    );
}
```

Minimal `header.php`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<?php wp_head(); // this function will place your CSS here ?>
<body>
```

Minimal `footer.php`

```
<?php wp_footer(); // this function will place your JavaScript here?>
</body>
<html>
```

Minimal `my_template.php`

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contact Template
*/
get_header();
// your content goes here
get_footer();
```

For more information see:

[wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

[enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

[Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Could you please help me a bit more? I have the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/6buxrf98/ . I only get style.css and default.js and not my template files. Do you know what is wrong? ( I `deregister` jquery because it is in my default.js file ;) )

Comment: Check `echo $template_file_name`.

Comment: Where should I place it? When I place it in index.php or in contactTemplate.php it doesn't show anything..

Comment: Place the following code anywhere in `Contact Template` file and you will see the file name: `echo basename( get_page_template() );`. Does it prints `front-page.php`? And enable debug mode in wp-config.php to check if there are any errors, warnings or notices.

Comment: Yes, it will give me the template file name (contactTemplate.php). So this works. Now I need to check if I can get the if else statement to work.

Comment: So copy this file name to the comparison (where the line ends up with the comment `// check  file name` in my answer).

Comment: Please see my JSFiddle. I put index.php and functions.php in the HTML section and my comments in the CSS section. If the if statement is true it will only change the background color of index.php https://jsfiddle.net/04169nv6/1/

Comment: You have to enqueue styles before you execute any of template functions (`wp_head();` in this case).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do I need to add something in my `header.php` before `<?php wp_head(); ?>`?